# Anaconda in my path

Tags: python, macos

I had previously installed `anaconda` on my Mac Book Pro but uninstalled it. I have reinstalled python from the Python site, but when I try and run `python` in the terminal it seems to still want to use anaconda in the path and I am getting an error. Any help would be appreciated.

```
"Richards-MacBook-Pro:Programming rapearl19$ python Firstprog.py 
-bash: /Users/rapearl19/anaconda/bin/python: No such file or directory"
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to run Anaconda-Clean to remove these files and directories. See the instructions here: https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install#anaconda-clean